# Linq group by and sum with multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables Orders and OrderDetails and i am trying to group by the username which is found in the orders table and then a sum of the quantities which is found in order details

Orders table

```
|Order ID    |Username|
|1           |User 1  |
|2           |User 1  |
|3           |User 2  |
```

OrderDetails Table

```
|OrderDetailsID| Qty| Order ID|
|1             | 50 |1        |
|2             | 20 |1        |
|3             | 30 |2        | 
|4             | 20 |3        |
```

How could i get the total quantity grouped by user using Linq?

This is what i came up with

```
from order in Entity.Orders
join od in Entity.OrderDetails on order.ID equals od.OrderID
where order.Status != 2
group order by new { order.Username } into users
select new StatsiticsViewClients()
{
     Username = users.Key.Username, 
     Qty = users.SelectMany(x => x.OrderDetails).Sum(x => x.Qty)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should group `od` instead of grouping `order`, because `OrderDetails` contains the property you're trying to sum.

And you don't need to use anonymous type within the grouping, because you group using only one column.

```
from order in Entity.Orders
join od in Entity.OrderDetails on order.ID equals od.OrderID
where order.Status != 2
group od by order.Username into users
select new StatsiticsViewClients()
{
     Username = users.Key, 
     Qty = users.Sum(g => g.Quantity)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Group `OrderDetails` and then you can get the Sum using `g.Sum(x=> x.Qty)` as well as Username from the Group Key field

```
  from order in Entity.Orders
    join od in Entity.OrderDetails
    on order.ID equals od.OrderID
    where order.Status != 2
    group OrderDetails by order.Username into g
    select new StatsiticsViewClients()
    {
         Username = g.Key.Username, 
         Qty = g.Sum(x=> x.Qty)
    }
```